# How can I change this multi colored logo to a single white one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, cs5, white

I am having problems with changing the color to white or black of this certain logo because it isn't a simple fast pasted one. I can use Photoshop and Illustrator (prefer photoshop) Both of my programs are CS5.1 but there isn't a difference with CS6. I've tried changing it from the blending options but the result was awful.
[image: this is the logo]

I've tried changing it from the hue menu.Still wasn't the best result.
[image: hue version]

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Already did some edits to the post.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Your post will be nominated for re-opening, but I'd advise you to edit a bit more: what is it about the hue attempt that you're not happy about? Please try and keep your critique question as concrete ans narrow as possible. They are a weird fit for our Q&A format as-is, so we are somewhat hard on them, sorry!

Comment: @Martin I don't follow. What aren't you happy with in that black and white result?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are on the right track.

Just mask the portion of the right that contains the text, and adjust the levels to make that part more dark.

[image]